# EF 4.3 Code First says Could not create constraint

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm having these two entities:

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool? IsAdmin { get; set; }
        public bool? DeletedFlag { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Vote> VoterUser { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Vote> VotedUser { get; set; }


    }

public class Vote
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime VoteDate { get; set; }
        public int Rate { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int VoterId { get; set; }

        public User VotedUser { get; set; }
        public User VoterUser { get; set; }
    }
```

and in the fluent api defined foreign keys like that :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(x => x.Id).Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.VotedUser).WithRequired(q => q.VotedUser).HasForeignKey(
                q => new {q.UserId});
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.VoterUser).WithRequired(q => q.VoterUser).HasForeignKey(
                q => new {q.VoterId});

            modelBuilder.Entity<Vote>().HasKey(x => x.Id).Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Vote>().HasRequired(x => x.VotedUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Vote>().HasRequired(x => x.VoterUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.VoterId);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

But when i try to create the database i got;

> "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Votes_Users_UserId' on table
>   'Votes' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE
>   NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints. Could not create constraint. See previous errors."

Where i make a mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [WillCascadeOnDelete(false)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679348%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to the Vote foreign keys, ie:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Vote>().HasRequired(x => x.VotedUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Vote>().HasRequired(x => x.VoterUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.VoterId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The error message already describes what happened. By adding the HasMany and HasRequired relations between the Vote and the User you create multiple FKs from User to Vote and the reverse.

If you delete a row in one table, this will cause [a cascading delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) on the other table and back again. This can result in a race condition so SQL Server prefers to block the transaction rather than cause runaway changes.
You can avoid this by specifying that one of the relations will not cause cascading changes with the ON DELETE NO ACTION  clause.

In your case I suspect that the primary entity is always the User, in which case the Vote->User relations should be marked with the NO ACTION clause.

To do this with the Fluent API, you need to use the [WillCascadeOnDelete(false)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679204%28v=vs.103%29) extension method.